# Enum Null Pointer Exeption

Tags: java, enums, nullpointerexception

I have used enum in the request parameter to accept brand values, but it's not a mandatory field. So I used `required=false`, but when I am passing brand `null` or empty in a param it's giving a null-pointer exception. Please show me how to fix this.

```
public enum Brand {
    Avis("A"),
    Budget("B"),
    Payless("P");

    private String value;

    public String getvalue() {
        return value;
    }

    Brand(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

```
@GetMapping("/locations") // getlocation
public ResponseEntity<?> searchlocationbyproximity(
    @RequestParam(value = "brand", required = false ) Brand brand,
    @RequestParam(value = "country_code") String country_code,
    @RequestParam(value = "postal_code", required = false) String postal_code,
    @RequestParam(value = "radius") String radius,
    @RequestParam(value = "state_code", required = false) String state_code,
    @RequestParam(value = "street_name", required = false) String street_name,
    @RequestParam(value = "city", required = false) String city,
    @RequestParam(value = "transaction_id", required = false) String transaction_id
) throws Exception {
```

Comment: Where in your code is the NullPointerException raised? Can you please share that line / method?

Comment: [Edit] your question and post the stack trace.

Comment: [mcve] because so far, it seems tha tthe problem you're describing is unrelated to the code you posted.

Comment: Is the exception happening when accessed via URL?  If so, include the URL resulting in the NPE.  If you are invoking the method directly via a test, include the invocation code.

Comment: FYI: Your getter should be properly cased: `public String getValue()` (with a capitalized "V") Looks like you may have a python background. Same goes for `searchLocationByProximity` and all your parameter fields (lowerCamelCase instead of snake_case). Read-up on Java naming conventions.

Comment: Do you use any converter? Like this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-enum-request-param

Comment: Thank You everyone for your suggestions. The problem is solved now the issue is not with the code, the logger was creating an issue